# How to build a path (that contains spaces) that can be used by ROBOCOPY or other?

Tags: c#

I am using 2012 Desktop Express.  I am doing a conversion of several programs from VB.NET to C#.  This problem is now holding up 3 of my projects.  I have did almost endless searches and have so many articles, but in none of them do the combine literal and variables together to create a new string.

So I have tried the @ sign in numerous ways, Path.Combine and a few others.  Every way either leaves me with no quotes in my string or with extra escape characters that ROBOCOPY spits out an error.  Here is my most promising work:

I need: "G:\2016 DPRoberts"

```
string sBAK_Folder = "\"" + sBAK_Drive + ":\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy") + " " + Environment.UserName + "\"";
```

output: "\"G:\2016 DPRoberts\""

```
string sBAK_Folder = Path.Combine(sBAK_Drive + ":\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy") + " " + Environment.UserName);
```

output: G:\2016 DPRoberts

```
string sBAK_Folder =(char)34 + sBAK_Drive + ":\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy") + " " +  Environment.UserName + (char)34;
```

output: "\"G:\2016 DPRoberts\""

Thanks for the consideration,
:} DPRoberts

EDIT1:
Thank you for your responses. I will try to add more detail.  Here is my code for a label that is clicked:  This a direct translation from my VB code, so I may have messed up at that point.

```
    // string sBAK_Folder = "\"" + sBAK_Drive + ":\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy") + " "  + Environment.UserName + "\"";
    // string sBAK_Folder = Path.Combine(sBAK_Drive + ":\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy") + " "  + Environment.UserName);
    string sUser_Folder = (char)34 + System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + (char)34;
    string sBAK_Folder = (char)34 + sBAK_Drive + ":\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy") + " "  + Environment.UserName + (char)34;
    Directory.CreateDirectory(sBAK_Folder);
    Process.Start("ROBOCOPY.exe", sUser_Folder + " " + sBAK_Folder + " /e /r:0 /w:0");
```

Each of the formats I listed above give me a invalid source folder from ROBOCOPY.

So in order to debug the problem I created a batch file with 2 lines:

ECHO %1

PAUSE

so when I run with each of the 3 examples I have tried:

```
    Process.Start("D:\\Temp\\BAK.cmd", sBAK_Folder);
```

I get the 3 outputs listed above, so my line of reasoning has been that it does not like the escape characters or the space, and these would be solved if I can find a way to send Double Quotes like I do in VB (I just put a chr(34) around each end) I have used the program for 50+ of users for about 4 years now.

Thank you,
:} DPRoberts

Comment: Your claimed output is implausible. Please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem, and a _precise_ description of that program's output and what you want instead. Be very careful about characters like `'"'` and `'\'`; be clear about when you use them as meta-characters and when you actually mean them to be in your output string. Note that VB.NET code should be directly portable to C#, so really you should just implement the VB.NET algorithm in C#. You will have better luck here providing a VB.NET [mcve] that works exactly as you want it to.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you mean what you say : `output: "\"G:\2016 DPRoberts\""`.
The extra `"` you're having are because what you're watching is a string, and all string in VS will have the `"` around them, so first & third example give you what you want.

When you pass the string, it shouldn't have them.

More over, if you still need them out, consider simply chopping the first and the last char from your string.

```
var v = "some string";
var cut = v.Substring(1,v.Length-2);
```